# Variable context in nested python function

Tags: python, autograd

This is probably a stupid question but I was going through the [micrograd](https://github.com/karpathy/micrograd/blob/master/micrograd/engine.py) repo and I came across a nested function that seems confusing to me.

```
class Value:
    """ stores a single scalar value and its gradient """

    def __init__(self, data, _children=(), _op=''):
        self.data = data
        self.grad = 0
        # internal variables used for autograd graph construction
        self._backward = lambda: None
        self._prev = set(_children)
        self._op = _op # the op that produced this node, for graphviz / debugging / etc

    def __add__(self, other):
        other = other if isinstance(other, Value) else Value(other)
        out = Value(self.data + other.data, (self, other), '+')

        def _backward():
            self.grad += out.grad
            other.grad += out.grad
        out._backward = _backward

        return out
```

The `_backward` function defined inside `__add__` is attached to a newly created Value object. `_backward` is using self and other. It is clear from the definition where it is getting those from but when we assign the `_backward` of the object to refer to nested `_backward`, how is it able to get the self and other objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The _backward function is able to get the self and other objects because it is a closure. A closure is a function that can access variables from the scope in which it was created, even after that scope has ended. In this case, the _backward function is created within the **add** method, so it has access to the self and other variables even after the **add** method has returned.

When a closure is created, Python creates a copy of the stack frame for the function in which the closure was created. This means that the closure has access to all of the variables in the stack frame, even after the function has returned.

In the case of the _backward function, it is created within the **add** method. When the **add** method returns, the stack frame for the **add** method is destroyed. However, the _backward function still has access to the self and other variables, because it has a copy of the stack frame for the **add** method.

This is why the _backward function is able to use the self and other objects, even though it is defined inside the **add** method.
simpler example to illustrate how closures work:

```
def outer():
x = 10

def inner():
    print(x)

return inner
```

inner = outer()
inner()